# Do I need an Amazon account to use a Kindle?

Tags: kindle, amazon, kindle-paperwhite

I am looking to buy a Kindle Paperwhite (7th gen).  Do I need an Amazon account for it to work? I just want to put books on it from my PC.  I cannot create an Amazon Account because I have no credit card, so will my Kindle register without it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use a Kindle without an Amazon account?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/can-you-use-a-kindle-without-an-amazon-account)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a credit Card to register your amazon account.
With amazon account, it is much easier to send your personal books to your kindle:

- send books an an attachment to your personal amazon email
- Use browser extensions to send webpage directly to your kindle

Alternatively you can send books via USB cable to your kindle without using an account.

Comment: Yes but when I for the first time start the Kindle and have to Input an account, can I put in an account that DOES NOT have a credit card associated with it?

Comment: Yes. and I believe the first time you turn the kindle on, it already knew the account associated with amazon (according to person who buy the device). In my opinion, start a chat session with amazon support and ask them any question you have using [this link.](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/contact-us/general-questions.html?skip=true)

Comment: No but I am not ordering it myself so it will not be my account.

I need to confirm this before I buy.

Comment: then ask amazon support as I said

Comment: @hacker804 It's possible that the person who buys the device can choose to NOT register the kindle to any account so that you have the option of assigning it to any account yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the paperwhite kindles... but with the kindle fires (at least that 2 latest ones) they read MOSTLY all epub and mobi files- but some just don't show up on the kindle. I have no idea why unfortunately, but if you have an e-book in the format of the actualy file- either epub or mobi- it will seem to recognize and store the book 80% of the time about. The method I use is the simple drag and drop from PC to correct folder on the kindle. Sometimes the books will show up in your library with a cover photo, and sometimes they will show up in your documents with the title and no cover, but still has the whole bookmarking/flip the page/ basic e-read features.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy a Kindle you will get an account. When you turn it on, it will prompt you to create an ID and Password and will assign you a unique Kindle e-mail, regardless of who bought it. You'll use the e-mail to load things onto the Kindle. Kindles will read PDF's as well as Kindle documents, look to see what formats are covered when you get your paperwhite. Non-Books are mostly held in a Documents folder. Amazon accepts PayPal and debit card purchases, so I assume that's what you're using. And in any case, if a Kindle has reverted to factory settings (i.e. buying a used Kindle), it will always make the user register it anyway.

A word of caution, though, take a look at what format the books on your computer are in. Amazon won't convert EPUBs to Kindle format. If you buy a Fire, you can use the Bluefire app to read EPUBS that you load manually. I don't think that will work on a paperwhite--I know it didn't on my Kindle Touch.

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER: This is by no means a marketing stunt, at the end of the day you know what is best but from your description it was clear to me that you  might not be making the right decision. Just my 2p.*

The benefit of using a kindle is the entire eco-system and infrastructure built around it by Amazon. If you take that away, the kindle is actually a pretty poor choice for an ebook reader. If you do not want to register your credit card and will not primarily buy your books from Amazon, you are subscribing to a world of hurt in my opinion. Please note that there are ad supported versions of the paperwhite and you need to pay extra to remove these. This brings me to the next leg of my answer.

My scenario was a lot like yours and I spent a lot of time researching the ereaders out there. I am confident to offer you the same advice and that is to actually go for a Kobo reader instead. That ereader is and a amazingly open device and very friendly towards people who would want to dump their own ebooks on to the device. Not only that, the book formats supports is great allowing you to read anything from comics (cbzs) to the industry standard epub files. In the future should you decide to buy books you can do so easily from the device itself using the kobo store.