# What are the negatives of linking a Kindle to an account?

Tags: kindle, amazon, drm, file-format, license

What are the cons to register a Kindle with an Amazon account?  Not so much whether a Kindle is [usable](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/6149/9853), nor whether account is [required](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/6426/9853) but, once account is linked to a device, what then are the downsides.

Comment: There are no cons at all. On the contrary, some Kindle features, e.g. collections, require registration. You'll also need to register your Kindle to download some of the optional bilingual dictionaries. 

If you have privacy concerns, create a throwaway email address, download the Kindle app, visit an Amazon website and "buy" a free book. Amazon will then prompt you to create an account that you could use to register your Kindle. (This method has the advantage, that you won't have to provide credit card details.)

Comment: I was amazed at the quantity of free books.